# Multiple Search terms using Ruby Searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have set everything up using ElasticSearch and SearchKick, however, I cannot get it to work quite like I want to. I need to have multiple searches.

My model, Car, has two attributes such as "Make" and "Year". I can do this:

```
Car.search( query: { match: {make: { query: "toyota" } }} )
```

How do I also find matches that belong to Toyoto but also belonging to a specific year, say 2012.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean ElasticSearch?

Comment: Yes, sorry. ElasticSearch (oops)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that year is either an attribute of your Car model or defined explicitly in your search_data config this should work:

```
Car.search "toyota", where: { year: 2012 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will returns cars in which make is "toyota" AND year is 2012

```
Car.search "*", where: { make: 'toyota', year: 2012 }
```

For make is "toyota" OR year is 2012

```
Car.search "*", where: { or: [[{make: 'toyota'},{year: 2012}]] }
```